# Use a navigation property for ListView strongly typed ItemTemplate?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, listview, model-binding

I am attempting to display the contents of a "Physician" table that has a 1-to-many relationship with a "SiteGroup" table.  I also want to display the value of 1 column of the "SiteGroup" table in the same ListView, ideally using the navigation property. Trying this does not work:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="PenroseDocLV" DataKeyNames="Name, Id" 
ItemType="Hospitalist.Models.Physician" UpdateMethod="DocCount_Update" 
SelectMethod="PenroseDocLV_GetData" OnItemCommand="LV_ItemCommand" 
siteID="1" sitename="PENROSE" >

<ItemTemplate>      
 <td class="thename"><%#: Item.Name %></td>
 <td><%#: Item.SiteGroups.Priority %></td>
 ...
```

My SelectMethod is:

```
public IQueryable<Physician> PenroseDocLV_GetData()
{ 
// Return any physicians that have the site as default or have been added to the SiteGroup   
   string SITE = "PENROSE";
   var query = db.SiteGroup.Where( S => S.DefaultName == SITE || S.Name == SITE )   
              .OrderBy( S => S.DocPriority).Select( P => P.Physician );

    return query;
}
```

I know the query works how I want it to, it's just the ListView markup that is causing errors.

I also want to be able to use the navigation property to `<%# BindItem.SiteGroups.DocPriority %>` in my EditItemTemplate.

What am I missing or how can I make this work?